# How to resize image from content attribute in CSS

Tags: css

I have a ::before pseudo class that calls an image and adds text via the content attribute. However the icon is too large. How can I resize it?

I'm currently stuck with the following code where none of the px attributes has an effect:

```css
.parentcategory3::before {
  content: url(https://unsplash.it/18) ' text that follows:';
  background-size: 100px !important;
  width: 100px !important;
  height: 100px !important;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="more_info parentcategory3">
  <span class="checkbox" style=""></span>
</div>
```

I have searched but always got to the same suggestions.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

If it is not possible is there a way to add a font awesome icon (while keeping the text after the icon!)?

Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: try to create full HTM/CSS code

Comment: @TemaniAfif Sorry, its updated now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read your question correctly, your best bet is probably to load the image as a background image, as [@Temani originally suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/48053726/1). Then adjust the `background-size` and `padding-left` values to fit your needs.

```css
.first::before {
  content: 'text that follows 1';
  background: url(https://unsplash.it/18) left center no-repeat;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-size: 16px auto;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.second::before {
  content: 'text that follows 2';
  background: url(https://unsplash.it/18) left center no-repeat;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-size: 12px auto;
  padding-left: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="first"></div>

<div class="second"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you try the zoom property to make the image larger and smaller? For example:

```
.parentcategory3::before {
  content: url(https://picsum.photos/150) ' text that follows:';
  zoom:50%;
  background-size: 100px !important;
  width: 100px !important;
  height: 100px !important;
  visibility: visible;
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the element at least `inline-block` so you can specify width and height.

Then if you want to use FontAwesome, you can add the code of icon directly into the content and use font-size to define the size of icon + text.

You can check [this link](http://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome/) to find the code of the needed icon.

```css
.parentcategory3::before {
  content: "\f007 text that follows:";
  font-family:fontAwesome;
  font-size:18px;
  width: 100px ;
  height: 100px ;
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px solid;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="more_info parentcategory3">
  <span class="checkbox" style=""></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesnt work in chrome and i cant change it to inline-block. Is there another way of resizing or perhaps using font awesome?

Comment: @AlphaX what is not working on chrome ? as am using chrome also :)

Comment: Thank you Temani! It's just that the inline-block isnt possible for me, so I went with the other solution by agrm which worked. Thank you very much again!

Comment: @AlphaX ok so my original solution but without inline-block :) .. well inline-block wasn't necessary but since i saw that you wanted to specifiy height/width i suggest it ;)